# Laravel API with AngularJS Response Data Parameter Not Always Present

Tags: angularjs

Using ngResource and making my Laravel 5.1 API end-point requests the response doesn't always have a data key.  In some requests I get response.data.theResponseData and in other requests there's no data key, and I get response.theResponseData.  In my API responses I've been adding the data key in the response JSON for consistency, but I've run into an instance where in my resource specific interceptor response.data is present, if I don't use the interceptor response.data is undefined, and I need to omit the data key.  Which doesn't sound like a bit problem, but if I'm trying to keep my responses consistent, I sometimes now get response.data.data.

Does AngularJS strip out the response.data after all the interceptors are invoked and I've entered into handling the response?  I'm hoping this is not just exhaustion and a stupid question, but I've been staring at this for awhile now.

Answer (score 0):

In angularjs response is response.data but when your laravel return method if your are sending response in data array then you will get response.data.data in response please check it in both place angularjs and laravel